# GitHub Pages and Jekyll content duplication and SEO issues

Tags: github, seo, jekyll, canonical-link

I'm looking at using GitHub Pages to host my blog and Jekyll to present it.

Presumably, whatever I commit will appear at `<yourname>.github.io` through Jekyll and at `https://github.com/<yourname>/<yourname>.github.io` in rawer form. See this [page showing links to live sites and to the source repos used to construct them](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/sites/).

Advice on SEO suggests that duplicating content within and across domains is bad SEO practice. See this [Google support page on duplication](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359) and this [Moz page on issues with duplication](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) both of which also offer possible solutions.

My question is two-fold:

- Is content duplication actually a problem for GitHub Pages in practice?
- If so, how does one apply solutions like canonical linking or `noindex` to the GitHub repo so that search engines know that your Jekyll site is the canonical one?

---

### Update:

Might be worth noting that I uploaded a "hello world" index file to my GitHub Pages repo and then checked the source for the page on GitHub. The GitHub source already contains a canonical link

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://github.com/guypursey/guypursey.github.io/blob/master/index.html" data-pjax-transient>
```

I assume it's this that would need changing for each file to point to the Jekyll version of the site but I can't see a setting in GitHub to handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duplicate content is unavoidable when using GitHub Pages with users and organizations if the repository is public

In general this shouldn't be a problem. See a [previous answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76924/will-google-penalize-me-for-duplicate-content-on-github-from-my-knowledge-base).

You do have a couple of options:

- Google and other search engines can't obviously access private repository which requires a paid plan.
- Switch to a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages). This will use a `gh-pages` branch instead of the `master` branch. Since GitHub's robots.txt only allows search engine crawling of the master branch and disallows other branches. So if the site is in `gh-pages` branch this will prevent Google from seeing the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a paid plan so your first option might work for me but I don't know how it works with the `github.io` URL (i.e., whether it'll work when private). I'm going to read the previous answer more carefully this evening and try these options out. If I can get this to work I'll mark this answer correct.

Comment: Switching my repo to private doesn't seem to have affected the serving of my pages so that'll work for me! If I go public again with the repo I'll consider switching the branches or switching to a project page as you suggest. Thanks for your help!